# JAVA Break Line in String in every occurrence of specific symbol

Tags: java, android

I get a STRING from API but the string do not contains any break Lines.

The receiver side is an android application and because the API is not mine and I want to break lines anyway, I have Decided to insert Something like this "@Break" into the string, So now then I receive the String I want to **replace** all the "**@Break**" with an "**\n**"

So I have made a simple line :

```
  Response.replaceAll("@Break", "\n");
```

In normal case it would work, I mean android Studio do not throw any exception on this and there is no logical problem.. or at least I thought there isn't...

The problem is (I think it is the problem, not sure) that then you insert \n inside a String the JAVA intercepting the string as "" (Empty) and not breaking the line.

Bottom line it is not working.. so the question is, is that really the problem ? and if it is how do I solve it ?

Edit: Some examples of going on Directly from the code.

```
    String Response = response.getOutput().getText().get(0);
            // Changing Response to Check the String
            Response = "Hello sir, @Break How are you today?";
            try {
                  Response.replaceAll("@Break", "\n");

                    .....
```

Out put:

```
Hello sir, @Break How are you today?
```

Comment: \n shouldn't make a string empty.
Have you double checked that the response isn't empty?

Have you got more of the code you can share?

Comment: What do you see that makes you think that it is not working? What is the output? In the UI? In a file? In console? The `replaceAll` method returns the result of the replacement, in your example you don't do anything with the result.

Comment: @user8159708 The response is not empty, if it is the code do not proceed at all (IF statement), and I do receive the string in the final distention (The App interface)  but without any changes in the string, now that I think it if the code did at least something she would completely wipe the "@Break"  but it not doing that. What Part of the code will be any use ?

Comment: Ok guys I am editing give me a moment.

Comment: @NickL make your comment as an answer, I will accept it. You deserve it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Response` is your string, `replaceAll` does not change `Response`. If you want that, put `Response =` before it to assign the result to your variable:

`Response = Response.replaceAll("@Break", "\n");`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Response =  Response.replaceAll("@Break", "\n");
```

Check the content of Response after assignment, Strings are immutable and you cannot modify the String. Replace method returns a new String which should assigned back.